# Jquery slide text vertically

Tags: jquery, text, slide

I am trying to make some text scroll vertically using jQuery, I have been following the code example on http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div

Please can someone guide me on how to achieve

1. Position the slider vertically
2. Make the text scroll vertically when the slider is moved up or down

**EDIT :** (comment on @lonesomeday's answer) I've already tried setting `orientation:vertical` and tried changing

1. `scrollWidth` to `scrollHeight`
2. `width` to `height`
3. `scrollLeft` to `scrollTop`

in the functions `handleSliderChange` and `handleSliderSlide` but that doesn't work

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/), you can do this easily with the orientation switch:

```
$('#slider').slider({orientation: 'vertical'});
```

In the example you're using, you should invoke it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide,
    orientation: vertical
  });
});
```

Note that you'll probably have to make some styling changes to make it look as pretty as the original example.

Comment: thank you for your time. I've already tried what you suggested, please see my edited question.

Comment: There are vertical slider tutorials on the internet (e.g. [this one](http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/vertical_scrollbar_demo.htm)). I'd suggest you try using one of them.